# Get Images by rectangle

Tags: java, image, pdf, pdfbox

I have this method which can extract text in a specific location in the pdf

```
public static void getTextByRectangle(PDDocument doc,Rectangle rect) throws IOException{
    PDFTextStripperByArea stripper = new PDFTextStripperByArea();
    stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
    stripper.addRegion( "class1", rect );
    PDPage firstPage = doc.getPage(0);
    stripper.extractRegions( firstPage );
    System.out.println( "Text in the area:" + rect );
    System.out.println( stripper.getTextForRegion( "class1" ) );
}
```

Is it possible to do the same thing but for extracting images??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can extract all images, and compare the position of **rect** and **images**. Here is the example by [pdfbox](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PrintImageLocations.java?revision=1732938&view=markup). This can get image locations.

1. You need create a class extends `PDFStreamEngine`. Like this,

   `public class PrintImageLocations extends PDFStreamEngine`
2. You should override `processOperator`. And from **ctmNew**, you can get the image location, then compare **image** with yours **rect**, you will get the right image.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void processOperator(Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands)  throws IOException {
       String operation = operator.getName();
       if ("Do".equals(operation)) {
           COSName objectName = (COSName) operands.get(0);
           PDXObject xobject = getResources().getXObject(objectName);
           if (xobject instanceof PDImageXObject) {
                PDImageXObject image = (PDImageXObject) xobject;
                Matrix ctmNew = getGraphicsState().getCurrentTransformationMatrix();
                float imageXScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorX();
                float imageYScale = ctmNew.getScalingFactorY();
                // position in user space units. 1 unit = 1/72 inch at 72 dpi
                System.out.println("position in PDF = " + ctmNew.getTranslateX() + ", " + ctmNew.getTranslateY() + " in user space units");
                // displayed size in user space units
                System.out.println("displayed size  = " + imageXScale + ", " + imageYScale + " in user space units");
           } else if (xobject instanceof PDFormXObject) {
                PDFormXObject form = (PDFormXObject) xobject;
                showForm(form);
           }
       } else {
           super.processOperator(operator, operands);
       }
   }
   ```

Thanks mkl and FiReTiTi's advice.

Comment: Please no link-only answers; at least copy pivotal code from the example into your answer.